# Do I need to use async in js to play my video and listen to users input at the same time? If so, then how?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a webpage that, when you click a button, displays a video modal. While this video is playing, the user's microphone should be using speech recognition to fill in certain input forms. I have the video working and I followed [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-speech-recognition-and-speech-synthesis-in-javascript-9bcb213f6ddd) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eIRrowvLRk), so I think the speech recognition should be working...but it isnt. Would I need to use async and await? The only errors I have in the console are in regard to fontawesome not loading for some reason--none related to speech recognition. Here's my code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!---------Therapist Section--------->
    <section id="therapist">
        <div class="container" id="therapist_container">
            <div id="button">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="record()" id="therapist-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Talk with Delphi</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vid1Title" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <video width="100%" id="video1">
                      <source src="./static/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <form class="texts" action="/care" id="careid" name="care" method="POST">
                      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="what's your name?">
                      <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Where are you?">
                      <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="how can I help?">
                      <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
              $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].play();
                })
              $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].pause();
                })

              video = document.getElementById('video1');

              // window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;              

              function record() {
                  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || SpeechRecognition();
                  recognition.interimResults = true;
                  recognition.lang = "en-US";
 
                  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      console.log(event);
                      document.getElementById('name').value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                  recognition.start();

                  recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                    recognition.start
                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      // console.log(event);
                      document.getElementById('location').value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                  })

                  recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                    recognition.start
                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      // console.log(event);
                      document.getElementById('state').value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                    }
                    recognition.addEventListener("end", () => {
                      window.location.pathname = '/care';
                      document.care.submit();
                    });
                  })
                }              
              // video.addEventListener('ended',function(){       
              //    window.location.pathname = '/care';
              //    document.care.submit();
              // })
            </script>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock content %}
```